# Selenium Automation script

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I am writing selenium script for downloading email assets from Marketo, I am able to login through script but when I need from my script to click on "Export to excel button" , at that point it is throwing this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <button type="button" id="ext-gen188" class=" x-btn-text mkiExcel">...</button> is not clickable at point (438, 556). Other element would receive the click: <div class="ext-el-mask" id="ext-gen162"></div>
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.149)
```

Code:

```
from selenium import web-driver
from selenium import web-driver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
user_name = "xxx"
password = "xxx"
driver=webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\shubham.tyagi\PycharmProjects\SeleniumTest\Browsers\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://app-sj24.marketo.com/#AR1254B2")
driver.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys("")
driver.find_element_by_name("passwd").send_keys("")
driver.find_element_by_id("loginButton").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
# button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#ext-gen188")
button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ext-gen188"]')))
button.click()
```

Comment: Plase add some code to show us what you have tried and got this error

Comment: Update your question with the code please

Comment: From the error, it sounds like one element (ext-gen162) is covering/overlapping the one you are trying to click (ext-gen188).  It may help to share the page source (and styling) as well if possible.